# Jquery UI: draggable: stop event: wont allow drag restart

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have set up some jqueryUI dragging, but when I use the `stop` event, just like the example, it won't let me move it again

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable({
   stop: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#event-stop

Comment: Please show us a jsfiddle or the page where you have this error

Comment: If `stop` function has `return false` it will prohibit reuse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be working fine after the stop function executes.

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3MQZW/)

Comment: I found out what my issue was .. coffeescript was returning false